# How to initialize datetime picker with the arbitrary date & time value

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker

I have the following angular material datetime picker defined in my template:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker" 
                            (dateChange)="onScheduleDateChanged($event, element)" 
                        placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="element.date" >
                        <!--mat-hint>{{ dateFormat }}</mat-hint-->
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="$any(picker)"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <!--mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker-->
                        <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker [showSpinners]="true" [showSeconds]="true" [stepHour]="1"
                            [stepMinute]="1" [stepSecond]="1" [touchUi]="false" [color]="color" [enableMeridian]="true"
                            [disableMinute]="false" [hideTime]="false" >
                        </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
                        {{getDisplayDate(element.date)}}
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
```

It shows up like this:

[image]

When I press the datetime picker icon it shows up like this:

[image]

So it shows the current time instead of the time `{{getDisplayDate(element.date)}}` - the value of `mat-form-field` element.
Any idea how can I initialize datetime picker to show the date and time of `mat-form-field` element instead of the current time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, why you need `getDisplayDate(element.date)`?

As I understand, you want to display the same time in the `ngx-datetime-picker` modal as in the input-field before clicking the datetime picker icon. But this is the default behavior of the ngx-mat-datetime-picker. You define a date in the typescript file and link this like `[formControl]="dateControl"`.

Look at my created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-ngx-mat-datetime-picker-ydsyfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and let it flow into your example